# Download google script results to Excel VBA

Tags: vba, google-apps-script

I have a webApp (google sheets) that should transfer data to an Excel file.

In the script i'm currently returning something with ContentService.createTextOutput(), see [this](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxU2ZL39IdtMzQXu0OLJZz3shSOx1JNTCbe1_SCxunIimLJVqY/exec) link

In the VBA i tried with different codes, for example with

```
Sub Test()
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxU2ZL39IdtMzQXu0OLJZz3shSOx1JNTCbe1_SCxunIimLJVqY/exec", False
WinHttpReq.Send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "c:\test.txt", 2
    oStream.Close
End If
End Sub
```

With Runtime error 70, I tried also with WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 but with other errors (I suppose timeout)

I can download the whole file with [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS5xVZGepm5LH4KNyl1sUUpZ668pC0HStj335o_iR2C2qCafmmJ2wdyuKHd50U18ctKOaXmhh9AFywl/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv) link without problems, I see that the ContentService redirect the browser page (and the direct download does not) but I really don't know how to handle it with VBA (and I didn't find anything useful googleing)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found right now a solution with InternetExplorer.Application that is working, after hours of attempts and 10 minutes after making the question

```
Sub Test2()
'This will load a webpage in IE
Dim i As Long
Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object

'Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
IE.Visible = False

'Define URL
URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxU2ZL39IdtMzQXu0OLJZz3shSOx1JNTCbe1_SCxunIimLJVqY/exec"

'Navigate to URL
IE.Navigate URL

' Wait while IE loading...
'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
MsgBox (IE.document.body.innerText)

'Unload IE
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```